# What is LINK error L1083 : conn't open file?

Tags: assembly

I used masm5.0 to assemble and link to link it on dosbox.I'm newbie to assembly. This is my first program, which is supposed to convert a 16-bit number at 0500H to 5 corresponding digits, and then put their ASCII codes on 0510H~0514H.
Code:

```
DATA SEGMENT
ORG 0500H
INPUT DB (?)

ORG 0510H
RESULT DB 5 DUP(?)
DATA ENDS


CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START:
    XOR AX, AX
    MOV SS, AX 

    MOV BP, 0510H
    MOV BX, 0AH
    XOR DI, DI

    MOV AL, INPUT
    XOR AH,AH

    MOV CX, 5H

LP: XOR DX, DX
    DIV BX
    ADD DX,030H
    MOV [BP][DI], DX
    INC DI
    LOOP LP
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: It is obviously not a problem with your code, it is a problem with how you are linking it, but you haven't showed that. Anyway, check your file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINK error has nothing to do with the code you've posted. We can't possibly solve that.

However the code you've shown has some issues.

You say **which is supposed to convert a 16-bit number at 0500H** but you define only a byte at that location!

When writing the resulting digit you move a word when you should be moving a byte!

When writing the resulting digit you used a BP relative addressing which will use the SS register but you did not `ASSUME SS:DATA`

You initialized the SS register but what about SP?

The conversion routine is wrong because you need to write the result starting at the right! So initialize `mov di,4` and use `dec di`

Comment: @Nya If you swapped all occurrences of BX and BP you wouln't have to use the SS register at all. Much saver!